# How to get pathname of viminfo file after vim started

Tags: vimscript, viminfo

If vim started with `vim -i ~/tmp/.viminfo`, how can I extract that pathname after vim started?

Since upon exiting vim, history, mark, buf-list, etc will automatically write to that file, thus it must be stored somewhere.

The question is: how can I get that pathname?

Answer (score 4):

See the `viminfofile` option (`:help viminfofile`), which is set when using the `-i` command line flag.